# Is the following solution correct implementation of the Memoization approach for finding the N-th Fibonacci number?

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, fibonacci, memoization

As I understand *memoization* in dynamic programming, we use the output of the function with smaller input to find the current input's output.

I have written a code for finding the `N`-th element of the Fibonacci sequence. Is it a correct way of implementing it using *memoization*?

If not, can you explain where I went wrong and what I misunderstood? If yes, is there an alternate answer?

*My code:*

```
public class FibonaciQuestion {

    static ArrayList<Integer> series = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0, 1));

    public static int fibonacci(int n) {
        
        int len = series.size();
        if (n < len) {
            return series.get(n);
        }

        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = len; i <= n; i++) {
            sum = series.get(i - 1) + series.get(i - 2);
            series.add(i, sum);
        }
        return series.get(n);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.close();
        System.out.println(fibonacci(n));
    }
}
```

Comment: The word you are looking for is 'memoization'.

Comment: @user207421 I know it is memorization. What I am trying to ask is that is my implementation of memorization correct? Which user16320675 has given answer to, thanks by the way user16320675!

Comment: BTW user207421 meant 'memoization' (without `r`), not 'memo**r**ization' (with `r`) - see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), first line: "*Not to be confused with [Memorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorization).*"

Answer (score 0):

**Memoization** is an optimization technic which used with the so-called **top-down** approach, i.e. the problem is being divided into *subproblems* starting from the *top* (from the target input, which corresponds to the required final result), and by the means of recursion solution goes to the *bottom* (the cases for result is known in advance).

The point of *memoization* is to avoid recomputing the same values multiple times and **reuse** the previously computed results.

The code you've provided doesn't uses *top-down* approach, hence it's not an example of *memoization*. In your solution you're going from *bottom* to *top*, from trivial cases of the first and second fibonacci numbers `0` and `1` to the target `n`.

*Bottom-up* approach in *dynamic programming* is called **Tabulation**, it relies on loops (not on recursion contrary to *memoization*) and uses arrays to store intermediate results. Although you've used an `ArrayList` (a dynamic array implementation), which slightly less efficient in this case because we know the resulting capacity in advance, I think your solution might be considered a valid implementation of *tabulation*.

There's nothing wrong with this approach, but if you're required to solve the problem using *memoization* then it's not the correct way.

Before writing the code using *memoization* technic, let's make a small detour.

In essence, *Dynamic programming* is nothing more than an enhanced *brute-force* approach. While solving a problem with a brute-force we need to find all possible outcomes, the same applies *dynamic programming*, the difference is that while using *dynamic programming* we're storing every result of the computation and reusing it instead of recomputing the same values multiple times.

Let's start with creating a recursive brute-force solution (note in this solution indices start with `0` and input is non-negative because negative indices doesn't make sense and even if such validation is required it should not reside in a method responsible for performing computations as the Single responsibility principle suggests).

```
public static long fibonacciBrut(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 0; // base case
    if (n == 1) return 1; // base case
    
    return fibonacciBrut(n - 1) + fibonacciBrut(n - 2); // recursive case
}
```

It's very concise, but it will cause the same values to recomputed multiple times in different recursive branches because each branch can't produce its result without all its subbranches hitting the base case. It means if let's say `n` = `30`, values like the third, the fourth, etc. Fibonacci numbers would be recomputed many times. Also see this MIT lecture: [*lecture notes*](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-spring-2008/resources/lec19/), [*the lecture itself*](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/resources/lecture-19-dynamic-programming-i-fibonacci-shortest-paths/).

We have a *top-down* solution, now enhance it by applying *memoization*. We need to utile a data structure to store the results. For that purpose we can use a `HashMap`.

For convenience, I'll introduce an overloaded helper-method, which is a good practice to make the client code (which needs the final result) to only concerned with providing the index `n` and all other stuff will happen under the hood.

```
public static long fibonacciMemo(int n) {
    Map<Integer, Long> memo = new HashMap<>();
    memo.put(0,0L);
    memo.put(1,1L);

    return fibonacciMemo(n, memo);
}

public static long fibonacciMemo(int n, Map<Integer, Long> memo) {
    if (memo.containsKey(n)) {
        return memo.get(n);
    }

    memo.put(n, fibonacciMemo(n - 1, memo) + fibonacciMemo(n - 2, memo));

    return memo.get(n);
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Brute-force:");
    System.out.println(fibonacciBrut(5));
    System.out.println(fibonacciBrut(9));
    System.out.println(fibonacciBrut(35));
    
    System.out.println("Memoization:");
    System.out.println(fibonacciMemo(5));
    System.out.println(fibonacciMemo(9));
    System.out.println(fibonacciMemo(35));
}
```

*Output:*

```
Brute-force:
5            // the 5-th number
34           // the 9-th number
9227465      // the 35-th number
Memoization:
5            // the 5-th number
34           // the 9-th number
9227465      // the 35-th number
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/t28)

**Sidenote:** the most efficient way to calculate the `N`-th Fibonacci number is to iterate in a loop, maintaining two variables (*previous* and *current* number). Space complexity **O(1)** and time complexity **O(n)**. Basically, there's nothing that can be improved, I guess you were asked to implement this task using *memoization* technic because it's a simple problem, and you can focus on applying *memoization*.